# Receiving message from arduino through wifi

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I am new to arduino . I went through the basics . I want to receive message from arduino uno r3 in my laptop(ubuntu) . I have esp8266 wifi module . Arduino and esp8266 connection done . How do I proceed further ?

Comment: the simplest way is probably a running web server on your laptop, or perhaps mqtt/sockets, or a common cloud-based sever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the ESP8266 extension for the Arduino board in Arduino IDE,desktop. Then select the example code for ESP8266, use the Server example. If you wanna access your board outside your home then you need to open a port in your router.